# How can a string vibrating in a plane radiate sound?

Tags: waves, acoustics, radiation

If a plucked guitar string vibrates in a plane, how are waves produced that travel in all directions? I'd have thought that a vibrating string can only produce waves in its plane of motion.

Comment: Will a boat moving in a line only produce waves that move along that line?

Comment: No it wont, but I don't understand how that analogy works to be honest. A boat doesn't oscillate like a string, and the waves are on the surface of the water (i.e. in 2 dimensions). A sound wave travels in all directions. That said, I don't really understand how a boat manages to produce the waves it does either.

Comment: The movement of the boat pushes water out of the way, producing waves to the side of the direction of motion. The movement of a string pushes air out of the way, producing waves to the side of the direction of motion.

Comment: Is that as detailed as explanation gets? I mean the picture I have at the moment (with the boat) is that the boat pushes the water molecules so that the water immediately ahead of it is more dense, then in order to arrange themselves back into a pattern of uniform density the molecules spread out in radial shape. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that a string itself produces little of the sound you hear from an instrument; it's when the varying tension of the string is conducted into the body of the instrument, which in turn vibrates, that you get most of the sound.

Answer (score 1):

Let me please correct you. Real plucked string is almost never vibrating on one plane. The reason why is simple: eigenfrequencies of the both polarizations are usually very close and therefore you can't excite one without the other. It's safer to presume an elliptical polarization if you want a general case.

To your point: if you have a real instrument, the string produces almost no sound. The body of the instrument does. Then there you have privileged directions of course, but the lower registers are typically almost spherical in their directivities. Nevertheless, there are spectral regions where one direction is really more pronounced. It's important e.g. for microphone positioning. If you want to hear that, you must be in an anechoic room or in very open landscape. Otherwise reflections will more or less mix the sound for you.